# Event for apply discount coupon Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, discount

I want to add custom validation for Discount coupon that it can be used only on first order of any customer.

For this i want to create an observer for an event which will trigger when customer applies discount coupon code to his cart. but i cannot find that event.

Which event should i use?

Comment: it is a big task, you can reference this module demo https://shop.emiprotechnologies.com/customer-specific-discount-for-magento-2.html

Comment: You can use plugin for the same instead of observer.